# What's a word meaning "related to pressure"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there an analog to "electrically isolated" but related to pressure (or more specifically, air pressure) instead of electricity? Perhaps "pneumatically isolated"? I don't think "hermetically isolated" has the proper meaning. I also considered "manometrically isolated", but I think that seems to refer too much to manometry. I just want to express that two different rooms are not isolated from each other in terms of air pressure.

Perhaps "[piezo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/piezo)-isolated"? I can't find any precedence for this specific phrase, but it seems to express the correct meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does not directly refer to pressure, "atmospherically isolated" may work in the context of air pressure (contingent upon, of course, the specific linguistic context). If the air pressure is affected by factors other than [atmospheric pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure), it may not describe the situation accurately. But at least "atmospherically" has no implication of a measurement paradigm, unlike words like "manometrically" and "barometrically".

Comment: I would say they share an atmosphere if you want to go with the word atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a catch-all term for what you want.

When speaking of airflow within rooms, one typically says that they share a ventilation system.   Or that that are isolated.  Then you would describe the method of isolation. For example a [*negative pressure room*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_room_pressure), *HEPA filtration*, etc.

I suppose you could say the rooms are *barometrically isolated.*  Which means they are isolated from each other's air pressure.  But, I don't know that it is *quite* the correct term.

Comment: "barometrically" is a good suggestion I hadn't thought of. I prefer that to "manometrically", which I had previously considered, although "barometrically" still has some sense of measurement to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *want to express that two different rooms are **not** isolated from each other in terms of air pressure*, that presumably implies they're at the ***same pressure***. In which case they are...

> [***isobaric***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/isobaric) *- having or showing equal barometric pressure*
>    Also: ***isopiestic*** - having equal atmospheric pressure

I'm not sure there's much call for a word with the *opposite* meaning - having different pressures. That's just the normal state of affairs (and why draughts come through open doors and windows).

Comment: In fact, it seems that "isopiestic" can have the same meaning as "isobaric", at least in AE. Sources:
[[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/isopiestic)]
[[2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/isopiestic)]
[[3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/isopiestic)]
[[4](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isopiestic)]
My BE-specific sources either omit the word entirely or discuss ground water pressure.

Answer (score 1):

As an one time welder, we referred to gas-tight welds or joins, even when the medium filling the apparatus was liquid.

Technically the qualification in the EU. is: [EN 1708-1](http://www.en-standard.eu/csn-en-1708-1-welding-basic-welded-joint-details-in-steel-part-1-pressurized-components/?gclid=CIvr-MW3jb0CFWjmwgodBR0AQw). "Welding. Basic welded joint details in steel. Pressurized components." - it's still referred to as gas-tight on the factory floor.